# How can I make a std::list of arrays?

Tags: c++, list, std

I would like to make an std::list of arrays. specifically, I want a list of arrays of Borland Code Builders AnsiStrings.

the real kicker being that I would like the arrays to be allocated dynamically. How do I define the list? Im so lost here i dont know were to begin.

```
std::list<???> myList;
```

What am I putting inside the angle brackets? nothing i have tried will work.

Comment: Is that `AnsiString` as in BCB?

Comment: You should always associate "dynamic array" with "`std::vector`". And you should associate "strings" with "`std::string`". And you should associate "last resort" with "`std::list`". :) (Why a list?)

Comment: @sbi Yup. should have been more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef std::vector<char> char_array;
typedef std::list<char_array> char_array_list;
```

Or more appropriately:

```
typedef std::list<std::string> string_list;
```

Comment: Or, most appropriately: `typedef std::vector<std::string> string_container;` +1

Answer (score 2):

```
std::list<std::vector<char>> myList;
```

`std::vector<>` is the c++ way to correctly handle dynamic arrays.  Rarely should you need to use `new T[42]` directly to create an array.

```
std::vector<char> vc;
char ansi_str[] = &vc[0];
```

`ansi_str` in the code above is defined by the C++03 standard to be the address of the first element in the array (in C++98 it was allowed to return a proxy).

If you really want to use your `AnsiStrings` as strings you'd be better off using `std::string` instead of `std::vector<char>`.  Then you'll get all of C++ nice string features for free and you'll still be able to access the raw data with `std::string::data()`.  The one disadvantage to using `std::string` is the raw data is not available for modification.  If your `AnsiStrings` api needs to modify the data you'll be stuck with `std::vector`.

Comment: You may want to fix the spacing on the `>>`

Comment: You can modify the raw data of the string using `&myString[0]`.

Comment: @Billy: pragmatically you can, but the current standard does not require strings to be allocated in a contiguous space, some implementations might use copy-on-write semantics and... well you could hypothetically run into all sorts of trouble. In real life all string implementations are contiguous. I am not sure if any still has copy-on-write semantics (that is a problem with multithreading). BTW, c++0x requires strings contents to be contiguous.

Comment: @Yacoby: I purposely didn't space them.  C++0x is almost upon us, I'm tired of writing warty code.

Comment: @Pete I know C++0x altered the rules, but C++0x isn't official yet.

Comment: @sbi: We shouldn't let him get off so easy. :)

Comment: @sbi: Yep, lets make that `&myList.front()[0]`.

Comment: Fixed it.  Now your comments don't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it a list of arrays, use `std::vector`. Then it would be `std::list<std::vector<AnsiString> >`. You can use `resize` or `push_back` to add strings to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make std::list of std::strings instead?

But, why do you wish to use ansi strings?? Ansi strings are considered a 'text crime'.